# My Alert show up only in the second attempt in my React & Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I got a small bug in my code and don't really know what to do to optimize it, basically i m submitting data with my Redux action and if we got an error from the Backend end API, I want it to get the error pop up, in the case the password or email is incorrect, and if it is possible to get the same API response from my backend.

i m using Redux with react, to get started this is the action i m doing :

```js
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`/users/token/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
            error: error
        })
    }
};
```

and for my reducer :

```js
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: true,
            }
```

and finally my login page :

```js
    onSubmit: (value, { setSubmitting }) => {
      if(props.error === false) {
        props.login(
          value.email,
          value.password
          )
      } else {
        setAlertContent("The email or password is incorrect")
        setAlert(props.error)
      }
      setTimeout(() => setSubmitting(false), 3 * 1000)
    },
```

and in the return I have my alert from material-ui :

```js
        <Box>
        {alert ? <Alert variant="filled" severity='error'>{alertContent}</Alert> : <></> }
        </Box>
```

And thank you for your help and advice to optimize my code.

Comment: There are a couple of things that are not really clear in the code you posted: (1) in your reducer, it seems you set `state.error` to `true` both in case of successful and failed login, (2) in your login page you are setting your alert state when you submit the form but it should be done when you receive back the login result, instead (e.g. with a `useEffect` hook triggered by changes of `props.error`)

Comment: about the reducer i m not affecting any value to it so the error state is false when it success, but i believe you are right in the second point, thanks I will check out useeffect hook to Handel my event.